# SQL : Update row in table with replace word

Tags: mysql

I have table like:-

```
ID               Name                 Email                 UserName
1               Johen mak         jojo@yahoo.com
2               jameel mak        jojo@gmail.com
3               gawil gorgy       jojo@homail.com
4               mak jor           gop@yahoo.com
```

Now i need to insert into `UserName` value from `Email` column but without `@yahoo.com` or `@gmail.com` ....

But if there duplicit `UserName`. It must be add `_1` or `_2` ...

But if Any user have English `UserName`,we must not change, Only change and update if `UserName` not English. 
So The table must be like :-

```
ID               Name                 Email                 UserName
1               Johen mak         jojo@yahoo.com              jojo
2               jameel mak        jojo@gmail.com              jojo_1
3               gawil gorgy       jojo@homail.com             jojo_2
4               mak jor           gop@yahoo.com               gop
```

How can i do that !!!

Comment: How do you determine if a user have an English UserName ?

Comment: I need any solution to that and apply change for username by email without `@yahoo.com` if user name Arabic or empty , But if is English only replace space to `-`

Answer (score 0):

This is SQL-SERVER syntax,
EnglishNames is just a table with names, you have to fill it from somewhere.

```
DECLARE @users TABLE 
( 
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(32),
    email VARCHAR(32),
    username VARCHAR(32)
)
INSERT INTO @users
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) AS Id, Name, Email, substring(Email, 0, charindex('@', Email)) AS UserName
from Users

update @users set username = 
case 
    when (select count(*) from EnglishNames e where e.Name = username) > 0 then username + '_' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10))
    when (select count(*) from EnglishNames e where e.Name = username) = 0 then username
    end
where
id not in (
select min(id) from @users
group by username
)

select * from @users
```

Comment: Are this work in MySQL ?? and how can it check if there user have English user or no ??

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update an_users set `user_login` =

Answer (score 0):

This is for non English names:

```
set @rownum := 1;
SELECT U.Email,P.total_perfix,if(P.total_perfix > 1 ,  
CONCAT(P.perfix,'_', mod(@rownum:=@rownum+1,P.total_perfix)),P.perfix) as new_username
FROM USER_TABLE U , ( SELECT count(*) as total_perfix, 
SUBSTRING(Email, 1, INSTR(Email, '@') - 1)
                           AS perfix
                   FROM USER_TABLE group by perfix) P 
WHERE SUBSTRING(U.Email, 1, INSTR(U.Email, '@') - 1) = p.perfix 
AND u.name NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$';
```

if you just remove the last line you will have all [English and Non English]

```
AND u.name NOT REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$';
```

here is [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e24779/1)

Comment: what you mean `@rownum` ??

Comment: I try, But `Username` column is show me empty ?? why

Comment: as I understand from the question, you are creating username from the email addresses, I didn't know that gmail ,yahoo emails can contain Arabic letters if it so then just add: " WHERE Email NOT LIKE '%[A-Za-z0-9_.]%' "

Comment: No NO , look, i need to create `username` from `name` if `name` is english, if `name` is arabic, we create `username` from `email` without `@yahoo.com` or `@gmail.com` :) that is

Comment: i try your update but show me this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'p.perfix' in 'where clause'`

Comment: whats happen when you run: SELECT count(*) as total_perfix, SUBSTRING(Email, 1, INSTR(Email, '@') - 1)
                           AS perfix
                   FROM USER_TABLE group by perfix

Comment: post me the error, I even run it in phpMyAdmin and works fine