# Update row in table with replace word before check it if Arabic or English value

Tags: php, mysql

I have table like:-

```
ID               Name                 Email                 UserName
1               Johen mak            jojo@yahoo.com
2               على يوسف            jojo@gmail.com
3               gawil gorgy          jojo@homail.com
4               موسي شفيق           gop@yahoo.com
```

Now i need to insert into `UserName` value from `Email` if `Name` is in Arabic value, But without `@yahoo.com` or `@gmail.com` ....

But if there duplicit `UserName`. It must be add `_1` or `_2` ...

So The table must be like :-

```
ID               Name                 Email                 UserName
1               Johen mak         jojo@yahoo.com              Johen_mak
2               على يوسف         jojo@gmail.com              jojo
3               gawil gorgy       jojo@homail.com             gawil_gorgy
4               موسى شفيق        jojo@yamail.com             jojo_1
```

How can i do that !!!

Comment: First 2 cases could be handled using the mysql query but I doubt the duplicate replaces with _1 or _2

Comment: But how you get username?
From email or have separate text field?

Comment: I tried to make a trigger it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for this case but it does not check the duplicate usernames

```
update 
yourtable 
set username 
= case when NOT name REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' 
then substring_index(email,'@',1) 
else replace(name,' ','_') end ;
```

Now an alternative solution is to append `id` at the end of the username so that all the usernames are unique something as

```
update 
yourtable 
set username
= case when NOT name REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]' 
then concat(substring_index(email,'@',1),'_',id) 
else concat(replace(name,' ','_'),'_',id) end ;
```

Comment: good, But i don't need id for all user :), I need if duplicate usernames to add id , can you edit ?

Comment: In a single update statement it can not be done, however you can execute the first query and then run a php script to append with `_1` or `_2`

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981177/sql-update-row-in-table-with-replace-word/26982516?noredirect=1#comment42515706_26982516

Comment: Yes that is a select statement.However it becomes very complicated while using in update statement.

Answer (score 0):

user Replace :

```
 update table set username=(select replace(name,' ','_') from table);
```

Comment: but there are Arabic `name` , i need if there Arabic `name` to get it from `email` not from `name` :) read my post careful